# Docker-compose gives: "node|SyntaxError: Unexpected token import" error when running nodejs app that connects to MongoDB cloud cluster

Tags: node.js, mongodb, import, docker-compose, es6-modules

I have a working nodejs app that uses a MongoDb cluster on the cloud. I am trying to dockerize it using docker-compose up, but I keep getting this error:

**nodejs    |import Mongodb from 'mongodb';
nodejs    | ^^^^^^
nodejs    | SyntaxError: Unexpected token import**

Here is my dockerFile:

```
FROM node:12.16.1 as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY . /app
RUN npm install
RUN npm run build
COPY . .
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["node", "app.js", "daemon off;"]
```

Here is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  nodejs:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    image: nodejs
    container_name: nodejs
    restart: unless-stopped
    env_file: .env
    volumes:
      - node_modules:/node_modules
    command: node app.js 

  
volumes:
    node_modules:
```

Here is my package.JSON file:

```
{
  "type": "module",
  "name": "krakenchallenge",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "A Node.js app that will filter out valid transactions from given JSON files containging a list of transactions returned from running bitcoind’s rpc call `listsinceblock`. The app is configured to allow working  with both SQL or mongoDB types.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/abuaesh/KrakenChallenge.git"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "js",
    "mongodb",
    "sql",
    "nosql",
    "bitcoin",
    "transaction",
    "deposit"
  ],
  "author": "Noha Abuaesh <noha.abuaesh@gmail.com>",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/abuaesh/KrakenChallenge/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/abuaesh/KrakenChallenge#readme",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@babel/cli": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/core": "^7.10.4",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-object-rest-spread": "^7.0.0-beta.46",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.10.4",
    "babel-core": "^6.26.3",
    "babel-loader": "^8.1.0",
    "babel-polyfill": "^6.26.0",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "bitcoin-address-validation": "^1.0.2",
    "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "mongodb": "^3.6.0",
    "wallet-address-validator": "^0.2.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^1.18.10"
  }
}
```

Comment: Might be related to the NodeJs version. Import is supported from version **NodeJs 13.2.0**  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility > Notice the implementation note > From version 12.0.0: this feature is behind the --experimental-modules runtime flag

Comment: I tried upgrading the node version in the DockerFile:
`FROM node:14.7.0 as build`
But error persists.

Comment: 1. Did you re-build the image again or add the `up --build`? 2. Have you try to `require` as alternative?  `require('mongodb').MongoClient`

Comment: I added the --build and it worked! Thanks a lot!

Comment: Nice, adding the points as an answer, so others can benefit.

Answer (score 0):

The `import` statement is supported from version **13.2.0** [Browser compatibility Table](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import#Browser_compatibility)

Or From version 12.0.0, Users must explicitly enable this, using the `--experimental-modules` runtime flag.

Make sure to rebuild your image. `docker-compose up --build` will build your images before starting the containers.